# How to bulk insert a bunch of sequential numbers quickly?

Tags: sql-server

I recently inherited this SQL:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [tb_Whitelist]
--DECLARE @Counter INT, @Max INT
SELECT @Counter = 10000000
SELECT @Max = 19999900
WHILE @Counter <= @Max
BEGIN
    INSERT [tb_Whitelist] ([AvailableId]) VALUES(@Counter) 
    SELECT @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

It's taking 7 ish hours to run, which I'm told is too slow.  Are there any other bulk insert strategies that will allow me to insert a bunch of sequential numbers more quickly, or anything I can do to make this one run faster?

Comment: 7 hours to insert less than 10 million rows?, that certainly is slow

Comment: What's the largest number of rows in any existing table in your database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
INSERT [tb_Whitelist] ([AvailableId]) 
SELECT TOP (9999900) 
  10000000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM master..spt_values t1 
cross join master..spt_values t2
cross join master..spt_values t3
```

While loop will be slow, I just ran this query on my laptop which has 8GB Ram and pretty standard processor and it took me 1 min 45 sec to insert these records.

Comment: I just tried this out and it seems to work (and is way faster).  There are so many parts of this I don't understand though,  What exactly is going on with the cross joins?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid *RBAR*. Give it a try with a CTE and inserting in a single statement.

```
DECLARE 
    @counter INT = 1,
    @max INT = 50000;

with i (i) AS (
    select @counter i
    UNION ALL
    select i+1 from i
    where
        i< @MAX
)
insert into [tb_Whitelist] 
([AvailableId])
select 
    i
from i
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Actually...using a recursive cte to count is RBAR. Just not as obvious. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: @SeanLange yes, you are correct, it will generate the table in a "rbar" fashion. Thanks for the article. But will do the insert as single statement.

Comment: LOL. It isn't the insert that is rbar it is the cte. Funny that you say avoid RBAR and show a different method of RBAR but are going to stick to your guns when presented with a better way. The performance gets worse when the dataset gets bigger. Your code only inserted 50k rows, not the 10M the OP wants. Changing your code to insert 10M and adjusting M.Alis code. Your code took 2 minutes and 13 seconds on my mahcine. M.Ali took 20 seconds.

Comment: off course. i'm not "sticking to my guns", i am agreeing with you and did upvote Ali's answer. it is without a doubt faster. Thanks for the input.